# How to handle 3rd party JS in WebApps

Tags: javascript, dom

We use a heavy AJAX Web App that has have many 3rd party apps that does some service , but it leaks memory . Is it actually possible that we move these 3rd party to another DOM and it remains alive and interacts with the main DOM all the time ? If the 3rd party DOM is clutterd we need to alow users to flush it and then reopen --- without affecting the main DOM .
Specifically I am trying to segregrate using TinyMCE Editor in our application .

1) It should be there a different DOM (**Why ? So that it's no tloaded all the time** )  yet

2) Seperate from the existing DOM ( **Why ? so that it can be closed and refreshed without affecting the main application** )

Textareas get converted to a TinyMCe editor , if we can have something like onhover , call a specific DOM that is alive load the TinyMCE editor interact with the main DOM and get the things done ... we are good enough . I basically want the 3rd party stuffs in another DOM 
and yet accessible all the time .

Comment: have you tried using [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom). I had been working on a project where we used jsdom to work inside a sandboxable webworker, so we could set dom access and terminate the 3rd party code on given conditions.

Comment: What about an `<iframe>`? The second DOM is delivered for free.

Comment: Does the iframe co-exists ? I have AJAX intenstive stuff , so can the iframe be retained in the memory all the time ? Let me rephrase , I can do AJAX from Iframes as much as opposed to my main window ? And keep things segregrated ?